# fabrics in maas

Tags: maas

Is it possible to create 2 fabrics if I have a single NIC in the cluster controller server ?  I want to create 2 fabrics
both on eth0.

One for external management and one for openstack internal management

Comment: I want to move multiple vlans in different fabrics into one fabric. I tried manuplating the vlans using the command: maas user fabric update vlan:13 name=fabric name (the fabric name is in which I want to move the VLAN) but it does not work. Please let me know if there is some other command used for this or am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a very useful post for this issue here:

http://blog.naydenov.net/2016/01/maas-setup-deploying-openstack-on-maas-1-9-with-juju/#comment-4220